# ApplicationBar not showing up in Windows Phone HTML Template

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have created an application bar in code behind in a new Windows Phone HTML template. Originally the application bar was in xaml but I removed it. I created my application bar like I normally do in the code behind, although in this template for some reason it will not show up. I cannot figure out what the issue is, I have no errors. My code is below. The only thing I did in the XAML of the template is add a pivot control and I made the browser visibility false. My code is below. Any ideas?

XAML

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <phone:Pivot>
        <phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="APPLICATION NAME">
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.TitleTemplate>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="one">           
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem Header="two">
        </phone:PivotItem>

    </phone:Pivot>

    <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Visibility="Collapsed"
                      IsScriptEnabled="True"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                      Navigated="Browser_Navigated"
                      NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed"                          
                      ScriptNotify="Browser_ScriptNotify"/>

    <ProgressBar x:Name="PerformanceProgressbar"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 IsIndeterminate="False"
                 Visibility="Collapsed">
</Grid>
```

XAML.CS

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }   

    private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar appbar = new ApplicationBar();
        /appbar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

        ApplicationBarMenuItem settings = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
        settings.Text = AppResources.MainPage_Settings;
        settings.Click += settings_Click;

        appbar.MenuItems.Add(settings);
    }
```

Comment: Plz edit the question title, there is no HTML template in windows phone. It creates confusions.

Comment: I think problem in  settings.Text = AppResources.MainPage_Settings;. Update settings.Text with some hard coded text and then see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just creating an object ApplicationBar, but you are not adding it to your Page. [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has a [property ApplicationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.applicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which you should set with your created instance of [class ApplicationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar).

What would work:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
{
    ApplicationBar appbar = new ApplicationBar(); 
    /appbar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

    ApplicationBarMenuItem settings = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
    settings.Text = AppResources.MainPage_Settings;
    settings.Click += settings_Click;

    appbar.MenuItems.Add(settings);
    this.ApplicationBar = appbar; // or simply ApplicationBar = appbar;
    // you can also add Appbar directly = ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
    // and then modify via this property
}
```

Note that you can have many ApplicationBars (objects) and exchange them easily.

Comment: It was definitely `this.ApplicationBar = appbar;`. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code would work:

[click here for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        ApplicationBar appbar = new ApplicationBar();
        /appbar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;

        ApplicationBarMenuItem settings = new ApplicationBarMenuItem();
        settings.Text = AppResources.MainPage_Settings;      
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(settings );
        settings.Click += new EventHandler(settings_Click);

    }
```